# Grab multiple checked checkbox value (React JS)

Tags: reactjs

I'm an entry-level front end developer need help.

Here the case:
I want to grab multiple checked input(checkboxes) and then set it to my state which has an array value.
I mean in that input I have 99 checkboxes and I need to check 8 among them to set to my state that later will be fetched to my local MongoDB.

Gimme some direction, please. Thanks in advance.
Sorry, I don't provide some codes.

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [chkArray, setChkArray] = useState([]);


  const onChangeHandler = e => {
    //Creating a new copy of the existing Array
    const newChkArray = [...chkArray];
    //checking if the checkbox selected is true.
    //If yes then adding the value to the checkArray
    if (e.target.checked) {
      newChkArray.push(e.target.value);
    } else if (newChkArray.indexOf(e.target.value) >= 0) {
      //If unchecking an already selected item then removing it from the array
      newChkArray.splice(newChkArray.indexOf(e.target.value), 1);
    }
    //Updating the list with new items checked.
    setChkArray(newChkArray);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        id="chk1"
        name="chk1"
        value="chk1"
        onChange={e => onChangeHandler(e)}
      />
      <label htmlFor="chk1"> Chk 1</label>
      <br />
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        id="chk2"
        name="chk2"
        value="chk2"
        onChange={e => onChangeHandler(e)}
      />
      <label htmlFor="chk2"> Chk 2</label>
      <br />
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        id="chk3"
        name="chk3"
        value="chk3"
        onChange={e => onChangeHandler(e)}
      />
      <label htmlFor="chk3"> Chk 3</label>
      <br />
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        id="chk4"
        name="chk4"
        value="chk4"
        onChange={e => onChangeHandler(e)}
      />
      <label htmlFor="chk4"> Chk 4</label>
      <br />
      {JSON.stringify(chkArray)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```